# Why does weights argument in glm change the outcome of lsd?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, fishers-lsd

I have dataframe `df`.

```
df <- structure(list(t = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4"
), n = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L), m = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

`t` is the treatment group; the independent variable.

`n` is the sample size of each subsample.

`m` is the response; the number of successes out of the possible `n`; the dependent variable.

`m`/`n` is bounded between 0 and 1, therefore I use `binomial` glm.

```
mdf <- aov(glm(m/n~t, weights=n, data=df, family=binomial)) #with weights

mdf2 <- aov(glm(m/n~t, data=df, family=binomial)) #without weights
```

Then I use `agricolae::LSD.test` to run Fisher's LSD to test for significant differences in mean `m/n` among `t`.

**However, I get different results with and without using the** `weights` **argument, even though all subsamples have 10 individuals**

```
ldf <- LSD.test(mdf, 't')
ldf2 <- LSD.test(mdf2, 't')

output: 
> ldf$groups
    m/n groups
T3 0.87      a
T4 0.53      b
T1 0.45     bc
T2 0.21      c

> ldf2$groups
    m/n groups
T3 0.87      a
T4 0.53      b
T1 0.45      c
T2 0.21      d
```

In some cases, the differences are even more extreme. Which, is very unexpected to me. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: A larger sample size impacts significance. Otherwise we would do studies with $n=1$ and save money.

Comment: So it takes the sample size *within* each replicate into account to calculate  significant rather than *how many* replicates? What does the default ```NULL ``` use?

Comment: Basically. You can test by replicating each row of the data m times (via `df[rep(1:nrow(df), each = m), ]`) and fit a "simple" logistic regression. This should give you the same inference as the aggregated approach.

Comment: I guess my question is: If the difference is because of low sub sample size, what does the model do when I don’t pass the optional argument ```weights ```? Is it wrong if I don’t?

Comment: Yes. This would mean your group size is 1.

Comment: Okay. The reason I ask is that in some cases, separation among treatments does not occur, even when expected when I pass ```weights```.  So, all treatments with LSD as ```a``` for example. But when I remove this argument, separation occurs as expected. If the default ```weights=NULL``` is 1 and ```weights=n``` is 10 in all cases (10 sub-samples), the ladder should always have a larger sub-sample size. So, a larger sub-sample size has less 'power' or ability to separate treatments? This seems backwards to me. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: I see your point. The docu of the function is very low quality, I cannot really help. Btw. don't forget to adjust p values for multiple testing.

Comment: I think @MichaelM has already clarified this but - the two GLMs are different. From `?glm`, "For a binomial GLM prior weights are used to give the number of trials when the response is the proportion of successes". So basically, `mdf` is correct, `mdf2` is not.